# Close() Was Never Called on Database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I have tried closing my cursors after I retrieve my selected value on my spinner to see if that would help but it didn't. Since my spinners rely on other spinners to get the right values it crashes my app because there is no value after closing the cursor.

This only happens on when the API is <16.
Also it only happens right after I click on a spinner in my layout even before I select an item in the spinner dialog.

`onDestroy()`

```
protected void onDestroy() 
{
    super.onDestroy();
    myDataBase.close();
}
```

`close()`

```
@Override
public void close() {

if(myDataBase != null){
    myDataBase.close();
}
}
```

Here is the LogCat:

```
06-13 15:18:36.256: E/SQLiteDatabase(736): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.example.productguide/databases/products.db' 
06-13 15:18:36.256: E/SQLiteDatabase(736): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
06-13 15:18:36.256: E/SQLiteDatabase(736):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1980)
06-13 15:18:36.256: E/SQLiteDatabase(736):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:977)
06-13 15:18:36.256: E/SQLiteDatabase(736):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:956)
06-13 15:18:36.256: E/SQLiteDatabase(736):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1021)
06-13 15:18:36.256: E/SQLiteDatabase(736):  at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:745)
06-13 15:18:36.256: E/SQLiteDatabase(736):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:221)
06-13 15:18:36.256: E/SQLiteDatabase(736):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:149)
06-13 15:18:36.256: E/SQLiteDatabase(736):  at com.example.productguide.DataBaseHelper.createDataBase(DataBaseHelper.java:146)
06-13 15:18:36.256: E/SQLiteDatabase(736):  at com.example.productguide.ProductActivity.onCreate(ProductActivity.java:83)
06-13 15:18:36.256: E/SQLiteDatabase(736):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4397)
06-13 15:18:36.256: E/SQLiteDatabase(736):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
06-13 15:18:36.256: E/SQLiteDatabase(736):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
06-13 15:18:36.256: E/SQLiteDatabase(736):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
06-13 15:18:36.256: E/SQLiteDatabase(736):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
06-13 15:18:36.256: E/SQLiteDatabase(736):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
06-13 15:18:36.256: E/SQLiteDatabase(736):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-13 15:18:36.256: E/SQLiteDatabase(736):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
06-13 15:18:36.256: E/SQLiteDatabase(736):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
06-13 15:18:36.256: E/SQLiteDatabase(736):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-13 15:18:36.256: E/SQLiteDatabase(736):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
06-13 15:18:36.256: E/SQLiteDatabase(736):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
06-13 15:18:36.256: E/SQLiteDatabase(736):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
06-13 15:18:36.256: E/SQLiteDatabase(736):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

EDIT:
This also only seems to happen once even after closing and re-opening the app.

Comment: Why the down vote? No solutions posted here help me. If you down vote please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this [tutorial](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) to use my existing database to work. After using a few tips from user comments on the tutorial I started to receive the Close() was never called on database error.

After paying attention to my LogCat, I have found my fix. I wasn't closing my database in my `createDatabase()` and in my `copyDatabase()`. I am not sure if the fixes I added to my code will cause other problems for me in the future but testing it on the supported API's for my app, I have not received one error.

This is what I added to my code to make it work without any errors:

Instead of `this.getWritableDatabase();` in `createDatabase()` I used `this.getWritableDatabase().close();`

And I added

```
if(myDatabase != null)
{
    myDatabase.close();
}
```

in my try/catch under `checkdb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);` in `copyDatabase()`